# Retrofit 2.3 url call without return value

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a little problem with Retrofit. I want to call a url (its a fix IP with port number), and it has no return value. My code's run, but nothing happened. (It'll be a home automation system, and this code should open my garage. The server is a Jetty Servlet on a R.PI)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button garageBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.garageBtn);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.96.100:8080/")
            .build();

    GarageApi service = retrofit.create(GarageApi.class);

    garageBtn.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        service.garagemove();
        //Log.d("Retrofit", service.garagemove().toString());
    });


}}

public interface GarageApi {
  @GET("garage")
  Call<ResponseBody> garagemove();
}
```

Please help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with retrofit to effectively call the interface you need to enqueue it. 
So you need to do something like:

```
service.garagemove().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

And then implement (override) the methods onResponse and onFailure.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an api method that doesn't return anything (aka is returning void), you can use the internal java object [Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) as return value of the retrofit method.

Code example:

```
@GET("path/to/void/api")
Call<Void> garageMove();
```

[Here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-ignore-response-payload-with-call-void) you can read more about retrofit and void response.

Comment: I try this too, but nothing happened.

Comment: The client method doesn't return anything so you should check if the (backend) api endpoint is reached. Maybe the issue is there.